# Is the value of $x^y$ becomes undefined as both tends to 0?

Tags: real-analysis

I have a very basic doubt in analysis.I know that $0^x$ is $0$ and also any number to the power zero is one.$0^0$ is the situation where we have to apply both the conditions. So we cant define that.But i have doubt in very next part.If $x$ and $y$ are two variables what happens to the value of $x^y$ as both tends to zero? Is it undefined? Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
Consider the limit as $(x, y)\to (0,0)$ along the line $x = 0$ and along the line $y = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ and $y$ are two variables both tending to $0$ , the limit value of $x^y$ depends on the relationship between $x$ and $y$. The limit can be infinite or any finite number. If the relationship between $x$ and $y$ is specified, the limit is defined. If no relationship is specified, the limit of $x^y$ is undefined. See more explanation in pages 7-11 of the paper: https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14709220/Zero-puissance-zero-Zero-to-the-Zero-th-Power

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Consider $$A=x^y$$ and take the logartihm of both sides $$\log(A)=y \log(x)$$ and see what happens when $x\to 0^{+}$ and then $y\to 0$.